# Persiting a data over rows based on conditions in SQL

Tags: sql

I have a dataset where I need to maintain the same granularity, but I need to fix some rows based on a set of conditions

When these customers transition from "Active" to "Cancelled", I need to persist the first Cancelled date I see at each transition for every row after
The output I expect is in "DATE_NEW" - you can see the date is persisted to be the same as the first date you see when the status goes from A -> C

Example:

```
row_number,Customer,Status, Date, DATE_NEW
1,John,"A","3000-12-31","3000-12-31"
2,John,"C","2019-01-01","2019-01-01"
3,John,"A","3000-12-31","3000-12-31",
4,John,"C","2019-05-01","2019-05-01"
5,John,"C","2019-07-31","2019-05-01"
6,Eve,"A","3000-12-31","3000-12-31"
7,Eve,"C","2019-06-01","2019-06-01"
8,Eve,"C","2019-03-01","2019-06-01"
9,Eve,"C","2019-03-02","2019-06-01"
```

Comment: I'd use the window function `FIRST_VALUE()` if your database supports it.

Answer (score 0):

If your database is one of Postgres, Oracle, Db2, Firebird or MySQL. FIRST_VALUE() Returns the first value in an ordered set of values.
this link would help you:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/first-value-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 0):

My impression is to treat this as a gaps and islands problem. The islands are determined by counting off the preceding A rows so that each C row can then be associated with a transition. After the rows are numbered it´s just a matter of finding the earliest date.

```
with data as (
    select *,
        count(case when Status = 'A' then 1 end)
            over (partition by Customer order by "row_number") as acnt
    from T
)
select *,
    min("Date") over (partition by Customer, Status, acnt) as date_new
from data
order by "row_number";
```

Is "row_number" an actual column of data? If not you'll to substitute another ranking column.

Take a look here: https://rextester.com/WMK51667

Answer (score 0):

Shawn's approach is correct, but the logic isn't quite right.  It will set the wrong date for the "A" rows.

So:

```
with cte as (
      select t.*,
             sum(case when Status = 'A' then 1 else 0 end
                ) over (partition by Customer order by Date) as acnt
      from t
     )
select t.*,
       (case when status = 'A' then date
             else min(Date) over (partition by Customer, status, acnt)
        end) as date_new
from cte;
```